# _beginthreadex - дождаться завершения потока

Tags: c++, windows, многопоточность

Для выполнение определённой задачи пришлось прибегнуть к созданию дополнительного потока.
Новый поток я создаю в оконном приложении.

Д. Рихтер рекомендует использовать функции `_beginthreadex()` и `_endthreadex()`

```
HANDLE hThread;
unsigned threadID;

hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &ThreadFunc, NULL, 0, &threadID);
WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(hThread);
```

функция потока:

```
unsigned __stdcall ThreadFunc(void* pArguments)
{
    while(true)
    {
    //...
    }

_endthreadex(0);

return 0;
}
```

В результате поток запускается, выполняется его код, а функция `WaitForSingleObject` ждёт его завершения, чтобы потом закрыть его хендлы.

Проблема в том, что вот эта самая `WaitForSingleObject` подвешивает само окно.
Вопрос: если убрать из кода `WaitForSingleObject` и `CloseHandle(hThread)`, то как иначе следует дожидаться завершения работы потока с целью закрытия его хендла без подвешивания основной программы?

Comment: второй параметр WaitForSingleObject - таймаут

Comment: А смысл блокирующее ждать поток, в этом случае код можно и без потока запустить. Если это обычное оконное приложение - пусть поток посылает главному окну сообщение, что мол он отработал, а главный поток уже потом может вызвать WaitForSingleObject и зачистить ресурсы.

Comment: @VTT, второй параметр задаёт интервал ожидания. В данном случае я указал INFINITE - бесконечность, т.к. неизвестно, когда завершится работа потока. Этот вариант - не подходит (т.к. вешается основной поток), но нужно каким-либо другим способом основному потоку дать знать, когда завершается этот поток и вызывать CloseHandle(hThread). Ваши варианты?

Comment: @KoVadim, да смысла, конечно, нет блокировать. Я привёл лишь пример, который нужно изменить. Правильно ли я понял - предлагаете в функции потока после _endthreadex(0) отправить сообщение главному окну, например, SenMessage(mainHwnd, WM_MYEXITTHREAD) и уже в обработчике этого сообщения вызывать CloseHandle(hThread)?

Comment: Можно периодически вызывать WaitForSingleObject с 0 таймаутом, пока поток не завершится. Тогда основной поток вешаться не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Складывается впечатление, что вам хэндл потока вообще не нужен, а вы хотите просто его закрыть. Если это так, то вы можете вызывать `WaitForSingleObject` непосредственно перед выходом из программы. Или можете его вообще не закрывать - все незакрытые хэндлы при завершении программы закрываются системой.

Или даже использовать `_beginthread`. Оттого, что Рихтер не рекомендует ее использовать, совершенно не следует, что эта функция порченая и плохо работает. Рихтер в своей книге обосновал почему он ее не советует - давайте посмотрим чем же эта функция ему не приглянулась.

1. `_beginthread` не позволяет задать для потока отдельный дескриптор защиты. Даже не буду спрашивать нужно ли вам это.
2. `_beginthread` не позволяет создать поток в неактивном (suspended) состоянии. Вы это используете?
3. `_beginthread` автоматически закрывает хэндл потока по завершении функции потока. Возможно, это как раз то, что вам нужно?

В-общем, стоит критически относиться к рекомендациям авторитетов. Многие из них ни на чем не основаны, а отражают личные предпочтения и фобии этих самых авторитетов. Говоря конкретно о `_beginthread` - она ничем не хуже `_beginthreadex`, просто работает чуть-чуть по-другому. В некоторых случаях удобнее она, в некоторых - `_beginthreadex`. Нужно просто понимать их особенности и применимость в каждом конкретном случае.

Comment: Закрывать хендл один раз перед завершением работы программы - не вариант, т.к. при необходимости поток может быть снова запущен. И, следовательно, каждый раз по его завершении нужно хендл закрывать. Я не утверждал, что не хочу пользоваться _beginthread, но хотелось бы разобраться с _beginthreadex.

Comment: Вот такой пример: предположим, поток запущен функцией _beginthreadex. Функция потока раз в 5 секунд (while + Sleep()) проверяет значение глобального флага IS_STOP. В программе нажимаем кнопку, которая присваивает IS_STOP = TRUE. И  WaitForSingleObject ждём завершения. Программа подвиснет, пока "таймер" в потоке не отсчитает 5 секунд и не проверит IS_STOP. Затем хендл будет закрыт. Впоследствии поток может быть снова запущен. Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: @Ig_M, а зачем вам нужно немедленно вызывать `WaitForSingleObject`? Выставили флаг и занимайтесь своими делами, пусть поток дорабатывает свои 5 секунд. Вызывайте `WaitForSingleObject` когда действительно необходимо дождаться завершения потока, например, перед его повторным запуском.